# extract and truncate characters in unix

Tags: awk, extract

I am using `-cut -c12-16` command in an awk script but it is not working or may be I am not writing properly. The characters between 12 and 16 are variable and I want to take them out of the line from a file which starts with `999999`.

Comment: You need to include the actual commands you are trying as well. That being said `cut` is not an `awk` command. It is a program that runs on its own. `awk` has a `substr` function that might be of use to you for a similar purpose though.

Comment: You are trying to *add* `YYYYYY` to every line and for any lines that (after that) start with `YYYYYY999999` (so they start with `999999` originally) you want to remove whatever happens to be between characters 12-16 (new positions)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
$ awk '/^YYYYYY/ { print substr($0,1,12) substr($0,17); next }1' file
YYYYYY9999990519
```

#### Update:

```
$ cat file
YYYYYY651006178045E46178D
YYYYYY6510617ESTN5258534
YYYYYY999999621409112ET0
YYYYYY99999949234091EA201
```

```
$ awk '/^YYYYYY999999/ { print substr($0,1,12) substr($0,17); next }1' file
YYYYYY651006178045E46178D
YYYYYY6510617ESTN5258534
YYYYYY99999909112ET0
YYYYYY9999994091EA201
```

Answer (score 0):

Through GNU awk,

```
$ echo 'YYYYYY99999920120519' | awk '/^YYYYYY999999/{$0=gensub(/^(.{12}).{4}/,"\\1","g")}1'
YYYYYY9999990519
```

Comment: just change the start pattern.

Comment: could you post the script in your question?

Comment: yep, i can't be able to format the text which are present in your comment.